# Get value from SQL what was relation from other list. (Oracle APEX 21.11)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to display a value to the text field; it is from a SQL query. And that SQL's  `WHERE` keyword is from the list item.
Searching by ID in the selected row will return a single item.

```
SELECT SHOP_NAME, ID FROM M_SHOP WHERE ID = '(selected ID)';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use page item's name preceded by colon (`:`) sign. For example, if that ID represents `department ID` and page number is `1`, that could be

```
SELECT SHOP_NAME, ID FROM M_SHOP WHERE ID = :P1_DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is simple and very helpful for me!